# dynamically retrieve object method

Tags: php

I try to dynamically retrieve a method of a class but php throws an exception which says Undefined property: stdClass ...

and How i try to get the values

```
private function getExactValue($row, $name)
{
    $tempRow = clone $row;
    foreach( explode('->', $name) as $key => $value)
    {
        $temp = $tempRow->{$value};
        unset($tempRow);
        $tempRow = $temp;
    }
    return $tempRow;
}
```

> $row is an instance of an Object (not Std one)
>
> $name is what i need in the Object to traverse , for example when i need $row->student->gifts->totalPoint() just pass the student->gifts->totalPoint() to the method for $name parameter

can you tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: This looks like you try to treat language expressions like strings at runtime. That is not possible, something like `$row->student->gifts->totalPoint()` is _not_ a string you can manipulate with string functions. At least not under normal conditions.

Comment: no It works correctly but have problem with functions!, what's unordinary conditions??

Comment: Your last part of expression will try to access property named `totalPoint()`, this will *not* call `totalPoint` method. To call dynamically use `$tempRow->{$value}()` while `$value` in this case should be `totalPoint`, without braces.

Comment: @PeterM please post your answer, it's cool idea and somehow it works ;)

Comment: Well, Mike Brant answered, thats exacly what i meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do here. My first word of advice is that you are going about what you are trying to achieve in a very hackish way.  If you wanted a better way to be able to execute arbitrary methods on an unknown object, I would suggest you look into PHP's reflection capabilities.

That being said, the problem with your code would appear to be that you are trying to execute a method via string, where what you need to do is utilize the method's name.  What I would suggest is that within your loop where you explode the string on `->`, you try to detect if it is a method or not, and then act accordingly.  That could look like this:

```
foreach( explode('->', $name) as $value)
{
    $value_trimmed = rtrim($value, '()');
    if ($value === $value_trimmed) {
        // this is a property
        $tempRow = $tempRow->{$value};
    } else {
        // this is a method
        $tempRow = $tempRow->{$value_trimmed}();
    } 
}
```

You should probably also do some validation on the input as well to make sure you have valid property/method names for each segment, as well as add validation that the entire string is indeed properly formed (i.e. you don't have things like `foo->->bar(())`).  Of course this make no mention of how to handle array like `foo[0]->bar()` which you might also need to accommodate.

Comment: I know exactly what object is for traversing! but can you tell me about php reflection capabilities??

Comment: I think your solution would work as long as your input string is always properly formed.  It would break for example if it was passed something like `foo->b()ar`.  But considering there is no other input validation taking place within this function at all, that is probably one of the least of your problems.  For more on reflection either Google `PHP Reflection` or start reading the PHP docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php